# How to trace C threads in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, ffmpeg

I'm working on a video player based on ffmpeg. I found a LAG every time I try to exit. To figure it out, I put some log and found when it happened. But since ffmpeg forked into several threads using C. It's hard to decide **where** it happened. The logs won't tell me if time is wasted up by another thread.

I tried DDMS and OS.Debug.startMethodtraceing. But I just can't find detailed information.
Is there some command that can make the OS tell me which thread takes more time ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/stat` file for per-thread CPU utilization details